# Nevigation drawer on Dynamic layout

Tags: android

I have decided my layout on the basis of JSON response and make a layout at run time without any xml . I just take a Activity and call a api that give me json array on the basis of which i make my layout. I have no problem with that but now i want to attach a navigation drawer with this activity . I have used navigation drawer in my previous Activity by making them fragment but in this case i don't know how to convert my activity to fragment because in navigation drawer we need fragment not activity.

i just do not know how to convert this Dynamic ui to fragment

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.`dashboard`,container, false);
```

what should i write in place of dashboard because i have no xml for that particular activity ..

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(getActivity());
        View view = //view from JSON
        scrollView.addView(view);
        return scrollView;
    }
}
```

in navigation drawer handler

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new BaseFragment()).commit();
```